# Managed Metadata Navigation Creating Terms I Don't Need

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, managed-navigation

I am currently using managed metadata navigation for a site I am implementing. All pages will be created at the top level site as to enhance search features. Currently, when I add a page to the pages library, it creates a term in the term store (I am using friendly URLS).

Is there a way to avoid this besides turning off friendly URLs then associating the page with a friendly URL after the page is created? Currently, this is the only way I have found to avoid creating a term in the term store each time a new page is created.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to site settings > look & feel > Navigation, and at the end at the site you find the following choices. Disable them and you should be good to go.

[image]